# Change collapsible list header colour when expanded

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I am using Jquery Mobile(1.4) for developing cross platform applications.

I want to be able to change the background color of the Collapsible list headers when they are expanded  and set it back when collapsed.

Can anyone let me know how to change the background color of the "Collapsible list headers".

It would be better if we are able to do this through plain CSS.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Post your markup and what you've tried already

Comment: I’m pretty sure that appropriate classes are added/removed already when the element is collapsed or folded out – so go take a DOM inspector, figure out what those classes are, and then simply use them for formating elements in both states differently.

Comment: CBroe, I did try that but couldn't see the changes I was making in the following classes:- `ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed`   and  `.ui-collapsible-collapsed + .ui-collapsible:not(.ui-collapsible-inset) > .ui-collapsible-heading .ui-btn`. I want the background color of the list header to change when the list is collapsed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change The Color As you wish

```
.ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed > .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle{
    background:red;
}

.ui-collapsible-heading-toggle{
    background:yellow;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gVeL7/12/)

Comment: Thank you Kawinesh. I didn't want anything to do with tables though. But, yes, the "collapsible list header" changes to yellow, that is what i wanted to do simply using **CSS**. Because in my app there will be multiple collapsible lists and I don't want to handle change of color using a javascript function. I tried making changes in the CSS in these classes `ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed`, `.ui-collapsible-collapsed + .ui-collapsible:not(.ui-collapsible-inset) > .ui-collapsible-heading .ui-btn` in JQM 1.4 CSS but I couldn't get it working

Comment: @BetRob are you using icon in your collapsible set.

Comment: Yes, the expanded and collapsed icons.

Comment: @BetRob now is it k if so check as answered.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
 <div data-role="collapsible" id="clp" class="width70" data-mini="true">
 <h3 style="width: 120px">
                    Search
                </h3>

<div>
    <table data-role='table' id='tblSearch' data-mode='reflow' class='my-custom-breakpoint'>
        <thead id="tbl1">
            <tr>
                <th>HEADER1</th>
                <th>HEADER2</th>
                <th>HEADER3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtInsuredName" name="txtInsuredName" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtPolicy" name="txtPolicy" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtOT" name="txtOT" maxlength="10" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
  $('#clp').bind('expand', function () {
  $('#tbl1').addClass('greybackcolor');
  }).bind('collapse', function () {
  $('#tbl1').removeClass('greybackcolor');
 });
```

**CSS**

```
.width70 {
 width: 85%;
}
.greybackcolor {
 background: yellow;
}
@media (min-width: 400px) {
 /* Show the table header rows and set all cells to display: table-cell */
   .my-custom-breakpoint td, .my-custom-breakpoint th, .my-custom-breakpoint tbody th,     .my-custom-breakpoint tbody td, .my-custom-breakpoint thead td, .my-custom-breakpoint thead th {
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0;
 }
 /* Hide the labels in each cell */
 .my-custom-breakpoint td .ui-table-cell-label, .my-custom-breakpoint th .ui-table-cell-label {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Please find work demo : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gVeL7/5/)

Comment: Thank you Rohit!! but, what I want to achieve is, when this list is expanded I want to change the background-color of the header to change, and when collapsed it should revert back.

Comment: Have updated my demo link, please check and let me know if you need any more help

Comment: Rohit by headers I meant the collapsible list headers, we wanted the background of the collapsible list to change when the "+" symbol changes to "-" in the list. Thank you